# 'int' object has no attribute 'item' in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0])
```

when I print x

```
array([2, 3, 1, 0])
```

I'm using [this tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) and do

```
x.item(1)
```

And the error message is

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'item'
```

What is your suggestion?

Comment: I think , it works perfectly..

Comment: print you `x` first

Comment: Sorry, I already edit my question

Comment: try `pip uninstall numpy` . Then again install your `numpy` with using `pip install numpy`.

Comment: I am already used numpy in conda

Comment: Please wirte `print(type(x))` just before `x.item(1)` and tell us what output it gives.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do something like `x = x.item(1)`, and *then* try to use `x.item(1)` again?  We need the complete, *exact* lines of code that generate the error.

Comment: same error `'int' object has no attribute 'item'`

Comment: Please write `print('XXXXXXXXXX', type(x))` run the code, and then copy and paste the line in the output which contains 'XXXXXXXXXX'.

Comment: XXXXXXXXXX <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Now please do the same with `print('XXXXXXX', type(x), x.item(1)`. If you do not attract my attention by writing '@jacg' in your response, I do not know that you have answered.

Comment: @jacg by adsing one `)`  the answer `XXXXXXX <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 3`

Comment: Sorry about the missing `)`. There's your answer: it works! `x.item(1)` evaluates to `3`. In your original code, somewhere before the `x.item(1)` line, you have rebound `x`. Probably with a line that starts with `x = `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, between

```
x = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0])
```

and

```
x.item(1)
```

there is some code which changes the value of `x`. It's likely to be on a line that starts with `x =`

Comment: I don't know why taht was not working, but now it is working perfectly